# Can tmpfiles.d remove files based on time only (but not at boot)?

Tags: systemd

Is there a way to use systemd tmpfiles.d to clean ONLY based on time, and not also at boot?

I've tried 'd' and 'D', E.g.

```
#/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf
d /var/tmp 1777 root root 30d
```

and

```
#/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf
D /var/tmp 1777 root root 30d
```

but they both result in files being cleared at boot.

FYI I am running Debian 9 (Stretch).  If the default configuration files are used, files are not removed from /var/tmp by tmpfiles.d (at boot or by age).

Comment: The first line you have is correct... Can you gather more information to prove the behavior you're seeing? According to the documentation, `d` is not supposed to clean `/var/tmp` on boot. So it's possible something else is going on in your case... See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line you have is correct:

```
#/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf
d /var/tmp 1777 root root 30d
```

It shouldn't be causing the directory contents to be removed. See the [documentation for `d` and `D` options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html#d), which states:

> `d`
>
> > Create a directory. The mode and ownership will be adjusted if specified and the directory already exists. Contents of this directory are subject to time based cleanup if the age argument is specified.
>
> `D`
>
> > Similar to `d`, but in addition the contents of the directory will be removed when --remove is used.

It's possible this is conflicting with another configuration already existing in your system (one of the files shipped in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/*.conf`)

Also, beware that if you create a file named `tmp.conf` in `/etc/tmpfiles.d/`, you'll shadow the one with the same name at `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` if one exists (and systemd typically ships this file), so you might be inadvertently removing configuration you meant to keep around. (Then, again, that's the way to drop that configuration, so you can override.)

If your systemd version is recent enough, you can try the command [`systemd-tmpfiles --cat-config`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html#--cat-config) to see your full configuration, which might help you see other unexpected lines you might have for `/var/tmp` which are causing interference, or compare "before" vs. "after" when you drop a new configuration file (e.g. show you that lines from the configuration file with the same name in `/usr` were dropped.)

Comment: Thanks!  I've been testing the 'd' variant and it seems to work.  I'll keep watching for exceptions. Thanks for the `systemd-tmpfiles --cat-config` command, it will be available in Debian 10.